# FancyBox does not work when opening URL

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Please connect to this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/1726/

```
$.fancybox.open(
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com',
        modal: false,
        helpers:  {
            overlay : null
        }                
    }    
, {
    padding : 0   
});
```

You will see I am calling open method with href a site URL. That does not work.... if I change href to be an image URL, imagen is shown. How can I show an HTML page inside that popup?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the wrong format/syntax. It should look more like :

```
$.fancybox.open({
    padding: 0,
    type: "iframe", // for external pages
    href: 'http://fancyapps.com',
    modal: false,
    helpers: {
        overlay: null
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N5KEx/)**

**Notice** that if you want to open external sites, then you need to set `type: "iframe"` (no need to be specific for images though)